# How do I reduce the limits of this integral to solve it by reduction method?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I tried this with Wolfram alpha but it's not showing up anything.

$$\int_4^6 \sin^4 (\pi x) \cdot \cos^2 ( 2 \pi x) ~\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to substitute πx = t but integration becomes more confusing giving integral sin^4(t).cos^2(2t) from 4π to 6π
I want to solve this by reduction formulae

Comment: Please use MathJAX and put the integral directly in the question.

Comment: I don't have a computer. I'm on phone.

Comment: And also please demonstrate that you've made some effort. What are your thoughts on the question? What have you tried besides trying to type it into WolframAlpha?

Comment: Thanks to 'someone' who edited this question

Comment: I too am posting via mobile device, however it is still relatively easy to write $\int_4^6\sin^4(\pi x)\cos^2(\pi x)\text dx$.  One thing that I will rarely click on is a link to an external site.  Putting the whole content of your question inside the question body, perhaps with a link to further information, ensures that you lose fewer potential answers due to people not trusting external links (especially for those on mobile devices).

Comment: @abiessu thanks I was not familiar with mathjax and just to avoid the confusion ,I copied the image of rendered question from Wolfram alpha. Thanks I'll use mathjax next time 

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sin(Pi+x)%5E4+cos(2+Pi+x)%5E2+from+4+to+6) does it just fine.

The integrand can be simplified using trigonometric formulas to 
$$ -\frac38\cos \left( 2\,\pi\,x \right) +\frac14\cos \left( 4\,\pi\,x
 \right) -\frac18\cos \left( 6\,\pi\,x \right) +\frac{1}{32}\cos \left( 8\,\pi
\,x \right) +{\frac{7}{32}}
$$
Since the integral of any of these cosines over a period is $0$, the result should just be $$\int_4^6 \frac{7}{32}\; dx = \frac{7}{16}$$

Comment: Go easy on a kid sir, can you tell me how did you do it?

Comment: Did you use reduction formulae?

Comment: Repeated use of $\cos^2(t) = \frac{\cos(2t)+1}{2}$,  $\cos(s)\cos(t) = \frac{\cos(s+t) + \cos(s-t)}{2}$ and $\sin^2(t) = \frac{1-\cos(2t)}{2}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I needed it to solve by reduction formulae